# Hyperspherical parametrization of a multi-qubit state

Tags: quantum-state

Can anyone please explain me in simple words how the hyperspherical coordinates can be used to parameterise multi-qubit states?

The state of an $n$-qubit system can be thought of as a point on the $\mathbb{CP}(2^n-1)$, which is not a sphere. Of course, for small dimensions we have some exceptional correspondences ([Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)), but my question is regarding the case of a general $n$.

Comment: you mean when we write parametrisations such as $\cos\theta|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin\theta|1\rangle$ and similar for higher-dimensional systems? I would say that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is close enough to a hypersphere to make this meaningful, as long as you remember that the states are defined up to a phase. I guess more formally what I'm referring to is the correspondence $\mathbb{CP}^n\simeq S^{2n-1}/U(1)$

Comment: @glS  Yes, this is exactly what I mean! So, given the correspondence you mention, how exactly would you write the amplitudes for an arbitrary multi-qubit state (up to the overall phase)?